TYPO3 Backend / Custom Tab Rendering
This might be a really ambitious task.
I try to extend the function "renderTabMenu" from
"vendor/typo3/cms-backend/Classes/Form/Container/AbstractContainer.php" with my own templates.
The problem is that there is no built in solution for this though the templates are kinda hardwired. (comment in source code)
I've already tried to find a solution via event listeners or extend the child class TabsContainer but without success so far.
Here's the function for the template rendering.
protected function renderTabMenu(array $menuItems, $domId, $defaultTabIndex = 1)
    {
        // @todo: It's unfortunate we're using Typo3Fluid TemplateView directly here. We can't
        //        inject BackendViewFactory here since __construct() is polluted by NodeInterface.
        //        Remove __construct() from NodeInterface to have DI, then use BackendViewFactory here.
        $view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TemplateView::class);
        $templatePaths = $view->getRenderingContext()->getTemplatePaths();
        $templatePaths->setTemplateRootPaths([GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Templates')]);
        $templatePaths->setPartialRootPaths([GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Partials')]);
        $view->assignMultiple([
            'id' => $domId,
            'items' => $menuItems,
            'defaultTabIndex' => $defaultTabIndex,
            'wrapContent' => false,
            'storeLastActiveTab' => true,
        ]);
        return $view->render('Form/Tabs');
    }

My goal is to use my own partial for the backend tab rendering located at
Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/ModuleTemplate/Tabs.html
Does anyone got an idea how to do this?

You could patch your TYPO3 version:
https://archive-2019.typo3worx.eu/2017/08/patch-typo3-using-composer/

@Mogens
Yeah that could be a step foward, that will at least change the problem with hardwired paths. Maybe i'll update my local dev env completly to v13 then.
But still don't know if there's a way to use own template/partials for tabs afterwards.
